# RabbitMQ: How to use complex expressions in Header Exchanges?

Tags: header, rabbitmq

Bellow are the headers of a message in a Dead Letter Queue. I'm using RabbitMQ.

```
__TypeId__: com.example.queue.TesteDTO
correlationId:  dfbc9457-8de6-9b77-b7ad-b259d1e2ede4
sequenceNumber: 1
sequenceSize:   2
x-death:    
  count:    1
    reason: rejected
    queue:  queue.raffael.teste
    time:   1478870283
    exchange:   
    routing-keys:   queue.raffael.teste
```

I want to declare and bind a Header Exchange using a complex expression, say:

```
x-match = any
x-death[0].count = 1
x-death[0].count = 2
x-death[0].count = 3
```

But it doesn't work. It seems to work only for simple expressions:

```
x-match = any
simpleExpression = 1
simpleExpression = 2
simpleExpression = 3
```

So, please, how to make references to array indexes and components instead of just simple expressions in Header Exchanges (RabbitMQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "dot" occurs in the AMQP spec only in regard to the routing key. The Headers Exchange is not supposed to parse the arguments keys. If there was a header with a string key "x-death[0].count" and a numeric value value 1, it would match, but there's only a header with a string key "x-death" and a value with type: array of tables.